# How to build jenkins pipelines only on github releases

Tags: jenkins, github, build, reverse-proxy, github-webhook

I have a repository that I can create a release for. I have jenkins setup and since the jenkins is hosted inside a firewall that restricts any communication from outside the network, github-webhook doesnt work. Also getting the reverse proxy to work is a bit of a challenge for me. I understand that the github webhook sends out a json payload and I can qualify it based on release. But as I previously mentioned, this won't work because jenkins and github cannot talk with each other.

Therefore, I tried this solution; Filtering the branches or tags that the jenkins will build on. The following are the things I tried and they all didnt work. Everytime I run a build, jenkins just builds it.

[image]

I also tried the below mentioned regex,

```
:refs\/tags\/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

I also tried [0-9] instead of d. It build it every single time.

Am I missing something ? Or is that how jenkins work ? Even though we qualify the builds to run only on certain tags or releases, if we click on build now, it just runs it every single time ?

My requirement is very simple. I want jenkins build to run only on the release I created even if the release is 'n' commits behind the master. How can I achieve this ?